# How to template match inside a contour?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

In an image I have retrieved **some rectangular contours** of **areas that I am interested in** and now I would like to **match what is inside that area with a template**. I have multiple templates but each rectangle would contain at most 3 matching templates and minimum 1 matching template. How exactly do I go about **matching the template to only what is inside the rectangle?**

```
if(numberVert == 4):
    #Creating a mask to retrieve only what is inside the block
    blockMask = cv2.rectangle(blockMask, (rx, ry), (rx + rw, ry + rh), (255, 255, 255), FILLED)
    #ANDing it with the inverted color filtered image mask
    blockMask = cv2.bitwise_and(cv2.bitwise_not(imgMask), blockMask)
    #Checking inside the templates list to see which image template matches
    for t in range(len(templates)):
        imgTemp = templates[t]
        #Getting the template width and height
        iw, ih = imgTemp.shape[::-1]
        #Attempting to match template to what is inside the blockMask
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(blockMask, imgTemp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        #Defined a threshold to establish a baseline for what may be a match
        tempThresh = 0.65
        #Get location where the match is greater than the threshold
        loc = np.where(res >= tempThresh)
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            #Draw possible matches
            cv2.rectangle(srcImg, pt, (pt[0] + iw, pt[1] + ih), (0,0,0), 2)
```

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-template-match-inside-a-contour/7911

Answer (score 1):

The approach is the same: replace youר full image with the sub image of the contour and match the template in the sub image

```py
x0, y0 = top_left
x1, y1 = bottom_right
# if the contour is defined by x,y,w,h fix x1=x+w and y1=y+h
sub_img_bgr = original_img_bgr[y0:y1, x0:x1]  # this is your new image
# convert to gray
result = cv2.matchTemplate(sub_img_gray, template_g, method_idx)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried following your implementation but I got an error. 
res = cv2.matchTemplate(subImg, imgTemp, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) C:\OpenCV\opencv-4.5.5\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:588: error: (-215:Assertion failed) corr.rows <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corr.cols <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function 'cv::crossCorr'